# Doing native javascript inside of a JST backbone.js template

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, jst

I am trying to do a loop inside of a JST file:

**data.who**

```
["Arthur", "Craig", "Dan", "Daniel"]
```

**JST**

```
<date><% data.who.forEach(function(myself){ %>
    <%= myself %>
<%  }) %></date>
```

No idea and couldn't find loops in the document ion for `JST`, just trying to apply logic from PHP.

Comment: What error are you getting ? What is parameter you are passing JST file?

Comment: You were correct, `data` undefined. Just copied the wrong information over, so assumed it was the code. Others may find this helpful, not too sure though.

Comment: @JamieHutber add your answer as an answer and not as an update to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was a little bit silly, but `data` was not defined inside the `JST`

Make sure you have defined it inside of your view calling the `JST`